# Proof verification related to a rotation of an operator and convexity

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $(\mathcal{H}, \langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ be a complex Hilbert space and $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ is the algebra of all bounded linear operators on $\mathcal{H}$.

For ${\bf T} = (T_1,\cdots,T_n)\in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H })^n$, we consider the following subset $\mathbb{C}^n$
\begin{eqnarray*}
JtMaxW({\bf T})
&=&\{(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n)\in \mathbb{C}^n:\;\exists\,(x_i)\subset \mathcal{H}\;\;\hbox{such that}\;\|x_i\|=1,\displaystyle\lim_{i\rightarrow+\infty}\langle T_k x_i,x_i\rangle=\lambda_k,\\
&&\phantom{++++++++++}\;\hbox{and}\;\displaystyle\lim_{i\rightarrow+\infty}\|T_kx_i\|\rightarrow \|T_k\|,\; 1\leq k \leq n\;\}.
\end{eqnarray*}

> Why the following facts which is taken from [this reference](https://inis.iaea.org/search/search.aspx?orig_q=RN:23012860)(theorem 3.8) hold?
>   [image]
>   Note that **Lemma 3.4** indicates that $\pi_k(JtMaxW_A({\bf T}))$ is convex for all $k\in\{1,\cdots,n\}$, where $\pi_k$ is the projection from $\mathbb{C}^n$ to $\mathbb{C}$ i.e. $\pi_k(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=x_k$, for all $k\in\{1,\cdots,n\}$.
>
> If the above claim is **false**. Is it true if $n=1$?

**My attempt:** Suppose now that $0\notin JtMaxW({\bf T})$, then $\forall\{x_i\}\in\mathcal{H}$ such that $\|x_i\|=1$ we have,
$$\langle T_k x_i,x_i\rangle\nrightarrow 0 \quad \mbox{or}\quad\|T_kx_i\|\nrightarrow \|T_k\|,\,\, 1\leq k \leq n.$$
Let us rotate ${\bf T}$, that is we consider ${\bf \widehat{T}}=(e^{i\alpha_1}T_1,...,e^{i\alpha_n}T_n)$. Moreover, if $\lambda=(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)\in JtMaxW({\bf  \widehat{T}})$, then there exists a sequence $\{y_i\}$ in $\mathcal{H}$ such that
$$\|y_i\|=1\quad \mbox{and}\quad\|\widehat{T}_ky_i\|\rightarrow \|\widehat{T}_k\|,\,\, 1\leq k \leq n.$$
i.e.
$$\|y_i\|=1,\,\,e^{-i\alpha_k}\langle T_k y_i,y_i\rangle\rightarrow \lambda_k \quad \mbox{and}\quad\|T_ky_i\|\rightarrow \|T_k\|,\,\, 1\leq k \leq n.$$
Since, $\displaystyle\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}\langle T_k y_i,y_i\rangle\neq0$, then $\lambda_k\neq0$ for all $1\leq k \leq n.$ Assume that there exists $\delta_k$ such that $\Re e(\lambda_k)\geq\delta_k>0$

> Why for all $x\in \mathcal{H},\;\|x\|=1$ we have $\Re e\langle \widehat{T}_k x,x\rangle\geq\delta_k>0$)?

Answer (score -1):

The claim as it stands is false because $JtMaxW(T)$ might be empty. Then clearly, $(0,\ldots,0)\notin JtMaxW(T)$, but also $JtMaxW(T') = \emptyset$ for any "rotation" $T'$ of $T$.

An example for which $JtMaxW(T)$ is empty is given by
$$
T_1 = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\quad\text{and}\quad T_2 = \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: If $n=1$, is the claim true? Thanks.

Comment: Please is Theorem 3.8 in this reference wrong?https://inis.iaea.org/search/search.aspx?orig_q=RN:23012860